# Order tracking link in confirmation mail in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to send a order tracking link on the confirmation email that magento sends when a customer places an order,that link should take customer to main page or the tracking page of the courier company. can someone guide me

say for example i'm using a Fedex for shipping of the orders placed by the customer & i want to add the field something like this on the confirmation email that magento sends to the customer when the order is placed....

EX.. Track your order https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried yet.

Comment: You can send an email when you ship an item (when the order is placed you probably won't know the tracking order). You can add additional information to the email such as you want. If you always use the same shipping method, you could amend the template to include this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento's default sales order email, you can edit the html in this location -  `app/locale/en_US/template/email/directory/sales/order_new.html`

Just add the link anywhere you want in that Html file

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help,

http://www.courierscripts.com

You can integrate this with Magento back end to generate tracking info along with order.